# aidl.exe'' finished with non-ze ro exit value -1073741701

Tags: android, windows, aidl

I have a normal android project which build well in macOS, ubuntu and other person‘windows.

I hava a new windows 7 pc. When environment is configured, There is an error.

```
...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\build-tools\29.0.2\aidl.exe'' finished with non-ze
ro exit value -1073741701
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 12 more
```

I try nearly any solution on website. Sadly they doesnot help me.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trying, such as changing android sdk version，using android studio sdk, I get to the right solution.

-1073741701 is 0xc000007b which is a kind of windows system error.

Here is a clue.
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b-error/#e

Downloading Microsoft Visual C++ pack helps me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170